# React-native-agora remote video quality very poor, only freezing

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am working on a react native video call app, I use react-native-agora, everything works fine except the
remote video quality is extremely bad, I can see nothing, it is only freezing.
I use react native agora version : 3.2.2

My rtcEngine init function :

```
/**
 * @name init
 * @description Function to initialize the Rtc Engine, attach event listeners and actions
 */
const init = async () => {
    const {token, appId} = await getToken();
    setAppId(appId);
    setToken(token);
    engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
    await engine.enableVideo();
    await engine.enableAudio();
    await engine?.joinChannel(token, `${session.id}`, null, 0);

    engine.addListener('Warning', (warn) => {
        console.log('Warning', warn);
    });

    engine.addListener('Error', async (err) => {
        if(err === 17){
            if(!engine){
                engine = await RtcEngine.create(appId);
            }
            await engine?.leaveChannel();
            setPeerIds(peerIds => []);
            await engine?.joinChannel(token, `${session.id}`, null, 0);
        }
        console.log('Error', err);
    });

    engine.addListener('UserJoined', async (uid, elapsed) => {
        console.log('UserJoined', uid, elapsed);
        // Get current peer IDs
        // If new user
        if (peerIds.indexOf(uid) === -1) {
            setPeerIds(peerIds => [...peerIds, uid]);
        }
    });

    engine.addListener('UserOffline', (uid, reason) => {
        console.log('UserOffline', uid, reason);
        setPeerIds(peerIds => [...peerIds.filter((id) => id !== uid)]);
    });

    // If Local user joins RTC channel
    engine.addListener('JoinChannelSuccess', (channel, uid, elapsed) => {
        console.log('JoinChannelSuccess', channel, uid, elapsed);
        // Set state variable to true
        setJoinSucceed(true);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem, for those who have the same issue, I let here my solution:

I just make this videoEncoderConfiguration :

```
await engine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration({
        dimensions: new VideoDimensions(320, 240),
        bitrate: 140,
        frameRate: VideoFrameRate.Fps30,
        degradationPrefer: 0
    }))
```